# Var(e|X), when e=Xu (from Hansen's Econometrics book)

Tags: variance, conditional-variance

I was working through Bruce Hansen's Econometrics book/notes and got tripped up over something that should be very simple. See the snapshot below, which comes from page 25 of his book [Econometrics](https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/%7Ebhansen/econometrics/Econometrics.pdf).

[image]

With regards to the variance of e conditional on X, here's how I thought of it:
$$ Var(e|X)=E[e^2|X]-E[e|X]^2= E[e^2|X] = E[X^2u^2|X]=E[X^2u^2]=E[X^2]E[u^2]=1\times 1=1$$

Wondering where I made a mistake and why he wrote the variance to equal $X^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost correct:

$$E[X^2u^2|X] = X^2E[u^2|X] = X^2 E[u^2] = X^2$$

Because $X$ becomes a constant once you condition on it.